# How can I let elasticsearch map base64 field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a json file as input to my Elasticsearch 7.10.1 cluster. The format of the json is something like:

```
{
              "data" : "eyJtZXRyaWNfc3RyZWFtX25hbWUiOiJtGltZW5zaW9ucy...
}
```

The data value in the json is a base64 of a json. How can I create a map in elasticsearch to decode the base64 value and make index on each field inside the decoded json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) to the rescue!! You can create an ingest pipeline that will decode the base64 encoded field and then parse the resulting JSON and added all fields to the document. It basically goes like this:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/b64-decode
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": "ctx.decoded = ctx.b64.decodeBase64();"
      }
    },
    {
      "json": {
        "field": "decoded",
        "add_to_root": true
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "field": "decoded"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can refer to that ingest pipeline when indexing new documents, as shown below:

```
PUT index/_doc/1?pipeline=b64-decode
{
   "b64": "eyJmaWVsZCI6ICJoZWxsbyB3b3JsZCJ9"
}
```

The `b64` field contains the following base64-encoded JSON

```
{ "field" : "hello world" }
```

Finally, the document that will be indexed will look like this:

```
{
   "b64" : "eyJmaWVsZCI6ICJoZWxsbyB3b3JsZCJ9",
   "field" : "hello world"
}
```